# i want to get the direction of the route from pointA to pointB on the google map by giving latitude and longitude

Tags: javascript, google-maps

```js
function initMap() {
    var pointA = new google.maps.LatLng(51.7519, -1.2578),
        pointB = new google.maps.LatLng(50.8429, -0.1313),
        myOptions = {
            zoom: 7,
            center: pointA
        },
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), myOptions),
        // Instantiate a directions service.
        directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService,
        directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
            map: map
        }),
        markerA = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: pointA,
            title: "point A",
            label: "A",
            map: map
        }),
        markerB = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: pointB,
            title: "point B",
            label: "B",
            map: map
        });

    // get route from A to B
    calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay, pointA, pointB);

}



function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay, pointA, pointB) {
    directionsService.route({
        origin: pointA,
        destination: pointB,
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
    }, function (response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        } else {
            window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
        }
    });
}

initMap();
```

```css
 html, body {
          height: 100%;
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
      }
      #map-canvas {
          height: 100%;
          width: 100%;
      }
```

```html
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

i am using the code of JSfiddle to get the direction from one point to another by passing starting and ending latitude and longitude , when i am running this code on JSfiddle it is showing the output or it is showing the direction on the google map but when i am using this code on my localhost , it is not working even it is not showing any kind of output , please help me to get out of it.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely it occurs since the page is not yet loaded once the map is initialized. In JSFiddle the default load type is `onLoad` (see `JavaScript` settings button -> `Load Type`) which means the script is invoked once the page is loaded and it explains why it works properly.

Having said that you need to trigger the JavaScript code once an HTML page is fully loaded,  for that you need to replace the line:

```
initMap();
```

with one of the following options.

**Option 1**

Utilize `load` event handler to initialize the map:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
```

Example

```js
function initMap() {
    var pointA = new google.maps.LatLng(51.7519, -1.2578),
        pointB = new google.maps.LatLng(50.8429, -0.1313),
        myOptions = {
            zoom: 7,
            center: pointA
        },
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), myOptions),
        // Instantiate a directions service.
        directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService,
        directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
            map: map
        }),
        markerA = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: pointA,
            title: "point A",
            label: "A",
            map: map
        }),
        markerB = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: pointB,
            title: "point B",
            label: "B",
            map: map
        });

    // get route from A to B
    calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay, pointA, pointB);

}



function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay, pointA, pointB) {
    directionsService.route({
        origin: pointA,
        destination: pointB,
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
    }, function (response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        } else {
            window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
        }
    });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
```

```css
html, body {
          height: 100%;
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
      }
      #map-canvas {
          height: 100%;
          width: 100%;
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pkpoymL7/1/) - JavaScript is referenced in head section (JavaScript settings `Load Type` is changed to `No wrap - in <head>`)

**Option 2**

Utilize callback approach to init the map:

```
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap"></script>
```

Example

```js
function initMap() {
    var pointA = new google.maps.LatLng(51.7519, -1.2578),
        pointB = new google.maps.LatLng(50.8429, -0.1313),
        myOptions = {
            zoom: 7,
            center: pointA
        },
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), myOptions),
        // Instantiate a directions service.
        directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService,
        directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
            map: map
        }),
        markerA = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: pointA,
            title: "point A",
            label: "A",
            map: map
        }),
        markerB = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: pointB,
            title: "point B",
            label: "B",
            map: map
        });

    // get route from A to B
    calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay, pointA, pointB);

}



function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay, pointA, pointB) {
    directionsService.route({
        origin: pointA,
        destination: pointB,
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
    }, function (response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        } else {
            window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
        }
    });
}
```

```css
html, body {
          height: 100%;
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
      }
      #map-canvas {
          height: 100%;
          width: 100%;
      }
```

```html
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap"></script>
```